# How to populate UIImageView with Array of urls?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an array containing image URLs, i want to create an image view with those urls(now with for loop).

But i am not getting an idea,how to make image view with URLs in the array
Hope some will clarify this

```
int x = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <imagearry.count; i ++){
NSDictionary *dict = [imagearry objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"img_url"]);
NSString *filePath [NSHomeDirectory()stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Library/Caches"];

    stringarry = [[imagearry objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"img_url"];

    int x = 0;

    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[stringarry objectAtIndex:0]];

    for(int i=0; i < [stringarry count]; i++)
    {

        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        img.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
        img.frame = CGRectMake(5+x, 0, 160, 110);
        NSLog(@"image: %@",[stringarry objectAtIndex:i]);


        img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[stringarry objectAtIndex:i]];
        [stringarry insertObject:img atIndex:i];
         [scrollView addSubview:[stringarry objectAtIndex:i]];

        x += 170;
```

Comment: What does "i want to create an image view with those urls" means? If want to create an ImageView for every URL then ahave a look to TTImageView of the Three20 library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UIImageView does not have property to display image from the URL.Hence
>   you might have to download it in NSDATA format then convert to
>   `UIImage`.Instead take a look at  AsyncImageView  and store instances
>   of AsyncImageView within your array.

Check this link : [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView)

Comment: it does have a property i think..

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyURL]]];

Comment: yes..true thats what i have mentioned in answer..but this approach is synchronous and hence will block the main UI unless the UIImages are downloaded in the array..Hence AsyncImageView which will continue downloading asynchronously

Comment: If the images are in the disk is better the imageWithData option, if they are images from internet use AsyncImageView.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `imageWithData` instead of `imageNamed` :

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[stringarry objectAtIndex:i]]];
[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```